# Remove characters from List<string> in between separators (from text file)

Tags: c#, regex, list, visual-studio, replace

Fast way to replace text in text file.
From this: somename@somedomain.com:hello_world
To This: somename:hello_world

It needs to be FAST and support multiple lines of text file.

I tried spiting the string into three parts but it seems slow. Example in the code below.

```
<pre><code>
    public static void Conversion()
    {
        List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines("ETU/Tut.txt").ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Please wait, converting in progress !");

        foreach (string combination in list)
        {
            if (combination.Contains("@"))
            {

            write: try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new 
                    StreamWriter("ETU/UPCombination.txt", true))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(combination.Split('@', ':')[0] + ":" 
                        + combination.Split('@', ':')[2]);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    goto write;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("At least one line doesn't contain @");
            }

        }


    }</code></pre>
```

So a fast way to convert every line in text file from
somename@somedomain.com:hello_world

To: somename:hello_world
then save it different text file.

!Remember the domain bit always changes!

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to perform on your input text exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not the fastest, but it is pretty fast with an expression similar to,

```
@[^:]+
```

and replace that with an empty string.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"@[^:]+";
        string substitution = @"";
        string input = @"somename@somedomain.com:hello_world1
somename@some_other_domain.com:hello_world2";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/daLx0L/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/daLx0L/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: 1) `RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;` is redundant as the regex has no redfinable anchors, 2) using a Regex instance Replace method does not make it faster, a static `Regex.Replace` would be  faster. In fact, to make it fast, the regex should be a static readonly private field with `RegexOptions.Compiled` option. Then, it would be almost as fast as LINQ.